# positioning and looping an objects in random order

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have created 3 balls and I want to run a loop that animates them by doing the following:

1. randomly positions them
2. give them a starting point
3. give them a duration

Here is the fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/X3SVp/1/

### Javascript

```
function flipper(){
    $('#ball_1').animate({
        "left": '-90',
    }, function(){
        $('#ball_1').animate({
            "left": '200',
        }, flipper());
    });
}

flipper();
```

### HTML

```
<div id="ball_1">
</div>

<div id="ball_2">
</div>

<div id="ball_3">
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#ball_1{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #354390;
    left: 200px;
    position: absolute;
}

#ball_2{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #354390;
}

#ball_3{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #354390;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by random position them!?

Comment: Please can you expand your question, demonstrate what you have tried to do and provide more complete code, such as your HTML in this case.  So that people don't have to go to the fiddle before being able to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker you can refer the code in JSfiddle, which he mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

## JavaScript

```
function flipper() {
    $('.ball').each(function () {
        var rndm = Math.floor(Math.random() * 201);
        $(this).animate({
            "left": '-' + rndm
        }, function () {
            $('.ball').animate({
                "left": rndm
            }, flipper());
        });
    });
}

flipper();
```

## HTML

```
<div id="ball_1" class="ball"></div>
<div id="ball_2" class="ball"></div>
<div id="ball_3" class="ball"></div>
```

## CSS

```
#ball_1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #354390;
    left: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
#ball_2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #354390;
    position: relative;
}
#ball_3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #354390;
    position: relative;
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jaq316/qLCnT/)

Comment: nice! can i position them randomally in y-axis?

Comment: Yes. Just use $(this).css('top, value) in the each loop.

Comment: i didn't succeed can you show me where to put it?

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaq316/qLCnT/7/
There i've done a lot of randomizing.

Comment: wow can you pleas enter quote for every action, please?

Comment: pleas see this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/9PYCv/

Comment: this what i'm taking about i want to move the fishes randomally

Comment: This should get you close: http://jsfiddle.net/jaq316/hV8Xk/

Comment: this is so sweet man... i don't even know how to thank you, i deeply appreciate it. Thanks so so much...

Comment: Great. I've updated the fiddle to limit the maximum speed at which the fish swim.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40126/discussion-between-alonblack-and-jaq316)

Comment: why they are always Cling to the left?

Answer (score 1):

As a point of guidance and without doing all the work for you.

Make a function which you call before flipper that sets each of the balls in a random x-y start position on the page.  I recommend giving each ball the same class of `ball` so you can do something like this

```
`$.('.ball').each(function(index, ball){
//do something with ball
});`
```

For that you will need 
http://api.jquery.com/each/
http://api.jquery.com/css/
and javascript math.random() http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp (perhaps not letting random be more than the dimensions of the visible page which you can get with `$(document).height() and $(document).width()`)

Also not forgetting that they will perhaps need absolute CSS positioning depending on the use-case.

Then look at another function which you can loop in this case `flipper` which will loop through `each()` of the balls and animate a random direction for a random distance and perhaps back again depending on what you want.